# HireVoice\Neo4j Annotation error

Tags: doctrine-orm, neo4j

I am getting this error:

[Semantical Error] The annotation "@HireVoice\Neo4j\Annotation" in property Entity\Site::$id does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

This is the Entity/Site.php:

```
    namespace Entity;


    use HireVoice\Neo4j\Annotation as OGM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

    /**
     * Class Site
     * @OGM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repository\SiteRepository")
     */
    class Site {

        /**
         * @OGM/Auto
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @OGM/Property
         */
        protected $name;

        /**
         * @OGM/Property
         * @OGM/Index
         */
        protected $domain;

        /**
         * @OGM/Property
         */
        protected $url;

        /**
         * @OGM/Property
         * @OGM/Index
         */
        protected $created;

        public function setName($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        public function setDomain($domain) {
            $this->domain = $domain;
        }

        public function setUrl($url) {
            $this->url = $url;
        }

        public function setCreated($created) {
            $this->created = $created;
        }

        public function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }

        public function getDomain() {
            return $this->domain;
        }

        public function getUrl() {
            return $this->url;
        }

        public function getCreated() {
            return $this->created;
        }
    }
```

This is the Repository/SiteRepository.php:

```
    namespace Repository;

    use HireVoice\Neo4j\Repository as BaseRepository;

    class SiteRepository extends BaseRepository {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh flipping A.  Just realized @OGM/ needs to be changed to @OGM\